# SQL Select Statement syntax DATETIME

Tags: sql

I want to include a column, where transaction date information is stored, in a select statement and format the return as 'mm/dd/yyyy'. I am looking for syntax that includes how the column name from the database is invoked.

Comment: You should return `datetime` values *as* `datetime` values, not as formatted strings. Date formatting is a concern of the presentation ("view") layer of your application, not the database.

Comment: This is extremely well documented and there are tons of questions on SO with the answer.  What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: I am using Microsoft Dynamics GP. The table I am querying is the Open Financial Transactions Table. One column I want to include is 'TRXDATE' which is a datetime type. The values stored are in'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. If my select statement is: Select OPENYEAR, JRNENTRY, TRXDATE from GL20000, as an example, what do I need to add so that the return for TRXDATE is formatted as 'mm/dd/yyyy'? In the table, if my return includes 500 transaction records, every date in the current open year may have been used.

Answer (score 0):

The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. If you only want the current date and not the time stamp, use DATE instead of DATETIME.

```
SELECT * FROM *table_name* WHERE *datetime_column*
```

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure what are you trying to achive here but I hope below will help:

```
--declare variables, datetime and date
declare @datetime datetime = getdate()
declare @date date = getdate()

-- select above variables
select @datetime as full_datetime, 
    cast(@datetime as date) as date_only1,
    @date as date_only2
```

Add some comment if need assitance.